# using merge with layouts giving error for one file, no error on other. same code!

Tags: android

I am creating a few layouts with the root element being `merge`.  inside the `merge` element i have a `ScrollView` containing a `TextView`.  Here is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/headingLayout"
    android:layout_above="@id/tabsLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/aboutTxt"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </ScrollView>
</merge>
```

I am getting 2 errors: there is no resource to match the `layout_below` and `layout_above` names i have put in.

I have another layout xml file including very similar components, some of which also reference `@id/headingLayout` and `@id/tabsLayout`.  Both of these XML layout files do not contain the component with name `headingLayout` or `tabsLayout`

Why is it that one layout file has no errors about these references and the other layout file does?  What the crap am i doing wrong, the app will build and run like i expect, until i add this merge to another layout?

I have even tried copying the xml from the working layout file, to find that it gives the same errors, something must be wrong with my new layout file.  I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, opening/closing eclipse..

Comment: Why do you need the `ScrollView` inside a `merge` tag if it's the only top-level tag in the file?

Comment: well if my `TextView` gets too large, wouldn't i need to scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this is a strange fix i have found for this.  the layout i have given in my question above(the one giving errors) is named `about.xml`.  the layout with no errors which also includes `merge` and references to other xml components is named `home.xml`.  the xml file including the referenced components is named `base_layout.xml`.

in the eclipse `Package Explorer` under the `layout` folder, items are listed alphabetically.  so the `home.xml` file came after `base_layout.xml`, and could therefore reference the components inside it.  Since `about.xml` came before `base_layout.xml`, `about.xml` could not reference anything inside `base_layout.xml`.

so i just renamed `base_layout.xml` to `aaa_base_layout.xml` so it would be first, and all errors go away.